# Как проиграть аудио запись из стриминга?

Tags: java, аудио

Как проиграть аудио запись из стриминга?

Код :

```
String stringURL = "http://интернетРадио/радио_128"; // Тут рабочая ссылка
InputStream is = new URL(stringURL).openStream();

AudioInputStream sound = null;
try {
    sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);        
    sound.read();

} catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
```

Ошибка :

> could not get audio input stream from input stream

Comment: Может быть не хватает кодека?

Comment: @Burunduk, в каком формате вещает интернет-радио по ссылке?

Comment: http://89.208.99.16:8088/zvezda_128   Как узнать формат?

Comment: @Burunduk, у меня ссылка не грузится. Могу предположить, что там `MPEG`, а `AudioInputStream` умеет только `wav`.
___

Для проигрывания mp3 можете попробовать [JavaLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html).

Answer (score 3):

### Кто виноват?

Как верно подметил [@Nofate ♦](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1984/nofate), по ссылке стрим в формате MPEG. В `AudioSystem` есть метод [`getAudioFileTypes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioFileTypes--), который возвращает (<s>кривой</s> вольный перевод документации):

> Массив типов файлов, в которых система умеет записывать.

```
AudioFileFormat.Type[] types = AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes();
for (AudioFileFormat.Type type : types) {
    System.out.println(type);
}
```

В моём случае вывод был такой:

```
WAVE
AU
AIFF
```

Как видно, поддержки MPEG нет. В этом и причина ошибки.

Если бы автор выписал ошибку полностью

```
Error: javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream
```

то можно было бы сразу увидеть `UnsupportedAudioFileException`.

---

### Что делать?

Проиграть MPEG из стриминга можно, например, с помощью библиотеки [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources.html) следующим образом:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import javazoom.jl.player.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String stringURL = "http://89.208.99.16:8088/zvezda_128";
        InputStream is = new URL(stringURL).openStream();

        Player player = new Player(is);
        player.play();
    }
}
```

Документация - [JLayer javadoc](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/index.html)